# New class dont sync with panel admin django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin-filters

i just defined new class for my project. When I run server i dont recive errors just dont appears on the admin-django Panel.

Here is the new class from `models.py`

```
class Stock_Clinicas(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    stock_min = models.DecimalField('Stock minimo', max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    stock_opt = models.DecimalField('Stock optimo', max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    stock_act = models.DecimalField('Stock actual', max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, default=0)
```

and here my `admin.py`. i'll put all code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from stock.models import *

from .models import Organization, OrganizationUser, OrganizationOwner


class OwnerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = OrganizationOwner
    raw_id_fields = ('organization_user',)


class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OwnerInline]
    list_display = ['name', 'is_active']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}


class OrganizationUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'organization', 'is_admin']
    raw_id_fields = ('user', 'organization')


class OrganizationOwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('organization_user', 'organization')


class Stock_ClinicasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('stock_min', 'stock_opt', 'stock_act')


admin.site.register(Stock_Clinicas, Stock_ClinicasAdmin)
admin.site.register(Organization, OrganizationAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrganizationUser, OrganizationUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrganizationOwner, OrganizationOwnerAdmin)
```

Forget said, when I use syncdb the tables aren't created. I'm using Django 1.5.

dont resolved yet

Answer (score 0):

In admin.py, rename your modelAdmin class to `Stock_ClinicasAdmin` (or anything else that your model name), and add this after the modelAdmin class declaration:

```
admin.register(Stoc_Clinicas, Stock_ClinicasAdmin)
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

```
class Stock_ClinicasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Stock Minimo', 'Stock Actual', 'Stock Optimo')
```

You don't have any fields called `Stock Minimo`, the field is `stock_min`, so you need to adjust this.

If you just created this app, make sure:

1. You add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`; it should have `stock,`
2. You might want to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to create the tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm adding a new feature to the app `https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations` i'm working on django 1.5.0